# Capybara checkbox and click on link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara

I have a table like this with many numbers, below particular row from this table.

```
<tr>
    <td>5100<td>
    <td> Number description<td>
    <td>long number description<td>
    <td>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="" value="5100" name="id_rola[]">
    <td>
    <td>
       <a href="javascript:documeny.frolazak_5100.submit();">
         <b><img src="temp/img/foto.gif"></b>
       </a>
    <td>
<tr>
```

Whats i try to do was for this number check checkbox and next click link, but with this i have a problem. Firstly when i do **check("5100")** this show me unable to find checkbox "5100", and next when i try click link with **find(:xpath, "//a[@href="javascript:document.frolazak_5100.submit();]").click** , this show me unable to find xpath.

For any suggestion thx.

### EDIT: ANSWERS

1. Check checkbox with particular value:

   **find(:css, ".checkbox[value='5100']").set(true)**
2. Click on image in link in row:

To do this i wrote:

> ```
> all('tr').each do |tr|
>   next unless tr.has_text?('5100')
>   @href = tr.all('td a')[0][:href]
> end
> visit @href
> ```

But this solution was be sloowly, so first i puts @href and then i could manipulate directly with params in this href and instead using method all simply visit this href. BTW why i dont think about it earlier :)

Comment: Try this code `first("input[type='checkbox']").set(true)` for checkbox

Comment: Thx for this, but i found yet solution for this checkbox **find(:css, ".checkbox[value='5100']").set(true)**
But still i have a problem with this link.

Comment: The link will not be found in the given HTML since the href is "documeny" instead of "document" - ie one has "y" and the other has "t". Not sure if that is just a typo in the question or the actual problem.

Comment: sorty this was my fault. There is "document" i wrote this by hand